# Uprading Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

when i trying to execute command " sudo do-release-upgrade " getting below erorr.
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
**Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.**

I have tried below commands ..

- sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get upgrade sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Please provide me the solution

Comment: Did you get any warnings/errors in any of those commands (including any missing lines in the output of `sudo apt update`).  Do you have any *holds* on packages that you made in the past?  (`apt-mark showhold`).  Did `apt-get dist-upgrade` show any packages available?

Comment: apt-mark showhold : yes " rabbitmq-server " is hold .
This package should not upgraded . hence put an hold.

Comment: That package needs to be upgraded before you can perform *release-upgrade* as the message in your question .. ie. you must *install all available updates for your release before upgrading* which you prevented from happening by placing a hold on specific package(s).  *An alternative is to remove the package; and you may find other package(s) also will be upgraded/removed on upgrade/removal of that package - being held by that hold*

Comment: Is it possible to upgrade to the latest version of OS without upgrading RabbitMQ? Because we must use the same version of rabitMQ and mongod. This is our challenge now.

Comment: No, your only other alternative is to re-install the OS (*If a desktop system, you can re-install non-destructively, but that will cause that program to be erased before install from ISO, then your manually-installed packages from Ubuntu repositories are re-downloaded & re-installed, without user files being touched*)  The [Ubuntu release upgrader](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader) tool which is used requires all upgraded package to be re-installed first; as that is what is QA-tested & supported; other methods you'll have to test & do yourself as unsupported

Comment: In case you depend on a very specific version of a program, I would recommend not to install it via the Ubuntu repos. Either install via a 3rd party repo (and disable that prior to running a distribution upgrade), via snap, via Flatpak or fully manuel.

Comment: (My prior comment that there are no alternative relates to Ubuntu Q&A tested & supported paths...   You can always treat your system as Debian which will achieve the upgrade  with a *fair* chance of success; but I won't advise how, but will warn that the Ubuntu release-upgrader tool I provided does more than just what Debian does even if 96% is identical - that extra ensures a working upgraded Ubuntu system, so do your homework first before you follow non-Ubuntu upgrade paths & fully-test it - if you keep exploring & find non-Ubuntu alternatives; be aware of the risks you'll take on)

Answer (score 3):

Your two goals – to `apt-mark hold` a deb-provided application AND `do-release-upgrade` the system – are incompatible and thus mutually exclusive.

The usual solution is to install the application using some other method than a deb. Pick a method that provides you the control that you need.

- Example: If you compile the application yourself, you need not `apt-mark` it... but you might need to re-compile it for a newer release of Ubuntu as the apt-provided dependencies change.

Alternately, you can put your deb-provided application in a container environment that is compatible with the version you need.

---

Debian-based systems like Ubuntu are based around a design that all applications and OS services share a common set of dependencies. When you `apt-mark hold` an application, you limit the updates of all of it's dependencies. And also thus all of the the applications that share those dependencies. Like a ripple in a pond, the single pebble (`hold`) has a consequence for the entire system.

This design tradeoff – common dependencies at the expense of backward compatibility – solved several nasty problems for Debian about 20-25 years ago, and was a key design choice that made new Debian (and later Ubuntu) releases possible with the limited volunteer participation available.